# Flipping the order of an infinite series and assigning it a value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, zeta-functions

I was recently wondering if there was some method to "flip" the series and still assign it a value for divergent series. To illustrate what I mean:

$$ S(x,n) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots + a_n x^n $$

We would like to define the flipped sum series:

$$ F(S(x,n)) = a_n  + a_{n-1} x^{1} + \dots + a_0 x^{n} $$

Hence, to do this we begin by: assigning $x \to x^{-1} $ and take $x^n$ common:

$$  S(x^{-1},n) = (a_n  + a_{n-1} x^{1} + \dots + a_0 x^{n}) x^{-n}  $$

Multiplying both sides with $x^n$:

$$ S(x^{-1},n) x^n =  (a_n  + a_{n-1} x^{1} + \dots + a_0 x^{n})$$

Taking limit $n \to \infty$:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}S(x^{-1},n) x^n =  \lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n  + a_{n-1} x^{1} + \dots + a_0 x^{n}) $$

Taking the second limit $x \to 1$:

$$\lim_{x \to 1 } \lim_{n \to \infty}S(x^{-1},n) x^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n  + a_{n-1}  + \dots + a_0 )$$

### Questions

Is the above proof correct? Can this somehow be extended to zeta regularization?

Comment: What happened to the limit with respect to $n$ on the right hand side of your last equation?

Comment: My bad. It was a typo ... Thanks to your comment It also made me realize I may have to swap the order of the limits. But I'm not sure ...

Comment: In your example, is $a_0 + a_1 + ...$ divergent? If that's the case, then "flipping" around doesn't change the partial sums in any way, so the divergent behaviour won't go away.

Comment: Indeed the swapping of the limits needs justification as it's not valid in general. I agree with @theindigamer that even if the result holds, it doesn't seem to help, assuming $a_0 + a_1 + \cdots$ is divergent. Your final expression is exactly the same as $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_n)$ since addition of finitely many numbers is commutative.

Comment: Your question is a nonsense. Do you understand analytic continuation ? Flipping a finite sum is trivial, flipping a series doesn't make sense. You need to look at the axioms of a  summation method $T(\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n) = C$. Then the power series regularization is defined by $T(\sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n+1}) = T(\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n)-a_1$ (shift invariance) and $T(\sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n})=T(\sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n/m})$. **It is not the case** for the zeta regularization which is defined by $T(\sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n})=T(\sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n^{1/m}})=T(\sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n/m}) = C$ (multiplicative invariance)

Comment: @reuns Can I have a link to the "axioms of a summation method"? I'm still trying to get my head around what can and can't be done with summation ...

Comment: Let $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ analytic for $\Re(s)>\sigma$, assume it has an analytic continuation including $s= 0$ so that $\displaystyle \overset{(\mathcal{Z})}{\sum_{n \ge 1}} a_n=F(0)$ (zeta summation). Let $G(s) = F(s) m^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n (mn)^{-s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n/m} n^{-s}$ then clearly $G(0) = F(0)$. Let $H(s) = F(ms) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-sm}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n^{1/m}} n^{-s}$ then clearly $H(0) = F(0)$. This is the multiplicative invariance of Dirichlet series and hence of zeta summation. Can you do the same with power series and Abel summation ?